# Converting shapefile in NAD27 from meters to decimal degrees to match xy data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, convert

I have a shapefile of a boundary (polygon) that has the following projection:

> NAD_1927_UTM_Zone_11N
>   Projection:   Transverse_Mercator
>   False_Easting:    500000.00000000
>   False_Northing:   0.00000000
>   Central_Meridian: -117.00000000
>   Scale_Factor: 0.99960000
>   Latitude_Of_Origin:   0.00000000
>   Linear Unit:  Meter
>
> Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_North_American_1927
>   Datum:    D_North_American_1927
>   Prime Meridian:   Greenwich
>   Angular Unit:     Degree

I need to pull climate data (in netcdf files) that is within this boundary.  That data is in x y coordinates and has the following information:

> XLAT
>              Size:       219x285
>              Dimensions: londim,latdim
>              Datatype:   single
>              Attributes:
>                          units = 'deg'
>       XLONG
>              Size:       219x285
>              Dimensions: londim,latdim
>              Datatype:   single
>              Attributes:
>                          units = 'deg'

There's no other metadata, so in order to align these files, I need to convert the shapefile to decimal degrees.  I tried using the Project tool, selecting the same coordinate system, but I don't see decimal degrees in the drop-down.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to Project to this geographic coordinate system.

Coordinate System>Geographic Coordinate System>North America>NAD 27.prj

> GCS_North_American_1927
>
> Angular Unit: Degree (0.017453292519943295) Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.000000000000000000) Datum: D_North_American_1927   Spheroid:
>   Clarke_1866
>       Semimajor Axis: 6378206.400000000400000000
>       Semiminor Axis: 6356583.799998980900000000
>       Inverse Flattening: 294.978698200000000000